# enable Mysql Binlog for only specific tables

Tags: mysql, data-warehouse, binlog, mysqlbinlog

I am using Mysql Binlogs to replicate data into a DataWarehouse.
I have many small Mysql Instances and I will be enabling Binlogs to all of those DBs and uses Nifi to collect changes and populate/update them into Destination Datawarehouse.

So my usage is not regular server replication nor for backup purposes.

Now my issue is that out of some 100 tables in source databases, I only need some 20 tables in my datawarehouse. Also some of the remaining 80 tables also has some sensitive user info content, which I don't need for warehousing.

All sources Mysql - 5.7
Destination mysql - 8.0

I had looking into many forums but could not get right answer for my scenario. Before I conclude there is no way to not to collect bin logs to specific tables, I would like to make sure if am leaving some options.

Moving data from one DB to another DB and then using Ignore DB option might not sound good for my use case. As I don't have much control on source databases operated by different teams.

Please help me with your suggestions.

Comment: *There is no MySQL option to ignore a table in binary log*. I n MariaDB there is a [feature request: binlog ignore table](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9353) , in MySQL I can't find one